# Javascript setTimeout in onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit, settimeout

I have small problem with a submit button.. When it's clicked I want it to perform different actions, but two later than the other one. I have been trying to use a setTimeout from Javascript and place some of the actions I want it to perform in a different function, but then my code doesn't work anymore because it doesn't know what 'this' is anymore. Any help please?

```
 function test(){
    $(this).addClass("voted");
    $(this).val('lighted up');
  }

  $(".stem").click(function() { 
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".red").addClass("filltherm");
      setTimeout(test,1500);
  });
```

Comment: I there any specific reason to  use this you can write it function test(){
    $(".stem").addClass("voted");
    $(".stem").val('lighted up');
  }

Answer (score 1):

`$(this)` will be `undefined` in function test as $(this) refers to the current element whose event has occurred and your function is separate thing, use a variable to store reference of it.

do like this:

```
var temp;

 $(".stem").click(function() { 
      temp = $(this);
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".red").addClass("filltherm");
      setTimeout(test,1500);
  });


function test(){
    temp.addClass("voted");
    temp.val('lighted up');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Store a reference to `this` in `_this` and pass that as a parameter to `temp`.

```
function test(el) {
  $(el).addClass("voted");
  $(el).val('lighted up');
}

$(".stem").click(function() { 
  var _this = this;
  $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".red").addClass("filltherm");
  setTimeout(function () {
    test(_this);
  }), 1500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store a variable holding the value of `this`:

```
function test($el){
  $el.addClass("voted");
  $el.val('lighted up');
}

$(".stem").click(function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  $el.parent().parent().parent().find(".red").addClass("filltherm");
  setTimeout(function() {
    test($el);
  }, 1500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`proxy` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to specify what `this` shold be for the function call:

```
setTimeout($.proxy(test, this),1500);
```